# Modified cell font cannot be saved (XSSF)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm coding with Apache-POI 5.0 for Excel, but got into trouble. That is, I iterate cells to modify their font sizes according to the length of the content (**the default font size in the file is 20**). The following example showed the bug: (Only core code)

```
    /**
     * Export the present seat table through an given BufferedOutputStream
     *
     * @param out the BufferedOutputStream to be written
     * @throws IOException            if <code>out</code> can not be written
     * @throws InvalidFormatException NEVER HAPPENS unless you delete <code>templateOfTable.xlsx</code>
     */
    void exportTable(BufferedOutputStream out) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        InputStream in = MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream(GlobalVariables.TABLE_TEMPLATE_P);
        assert in != null;
        OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(in);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
        XSSFSheet table = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
            XSSFRow r = table.getRow(row);
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                writeCell(students[row][col],
                        r.getCell(col, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK),
                        wb.createCellStyle());
            }
        }
        // TEST POINT 1   iterate over cells
//        for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
//            XSSFRow r = table.getRow(row);
//            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
//                System.out.println(r.getCell(col).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontHeightInPoints());
//            }
//        }
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        pkg.close();
    }

    /**
     * A method to write a cell.
     *
     * @param stu      the student to be stored
     * @param cell     the cell to be written
     * @param newStyle should be a new style, through <code>wb.createCellStyle()</code>
     */
    private void writeCell(Student stu, XSSFCell cell, XSSFCellStyle newStyle) {
        newStyle.cloneStyleFrom(cell.getCellStyle());
        cell.setCellValue(stu.getName());
        
        //KEY CODE
        newStyle.getFont().setFontHeightInPoints((short) (stu.isLongName() ? 17 : 20));
        newStyle.setFillForegroundColor(stu.isBoarding() ?
                IndexedColors.PALE_BLUE.getIndex() :
                IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
        newStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        cell.setCellStyle(newStyle);
        //TEST POINT 0
//        System.out.println(cell.getCellStyle().getFont().getFontHeightInPoints());
    }
```

At `test point 0`, the output will be like:

```
20
17
20
20
... (Several "17" and "20")
20
```

But at `test point 1`, the thing seems wrong:

```
20
20
...
20 (All the lines are "20")
```

That's the most strange thing, because in the output file, the color and content of every single cell is right, but the font sizes (height in points) are all 20.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `CellStyle.cloneStyleFrom` clones the cell style but not the font. So you are using the same font all the time to change the font size to either 17 or 20. So the last font size set gets used. That is 20 in your case.

In `Excel` storage, cell styles as well as fonts are stored on workbook level. Cells share cell styles and cell styles share fonts. Knowing this,  `CellStyle.cloneStyleFrom` is not really much useful. Like you use it, it creates a cell style for each single cell, even if those cell styles are exactly the same and should be shared. Also, as said, it does not clone the used font. And it also should not, because if it is the same font for different cell styles then the font should be shared. Background is that there are [limits for count of cell styles as well as for fonts in workbooks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3).

So if the need is varying cell styles and fonts dependent of conditions, then either you need creating all needed cell styles and fonts once before applying them to the cells, or you need a method which really is able varying only some special properties of cell styles or fonts. There is [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) for cell styles. But there is nothing for fonts until now.

In following complete example I provide methods to vary only some special properties of a used font. Also I am using `CellUtil` to vary only some special properties of used cell styles . That is complete, tested and works for `XSSF` as well as for `HSSF`. And it it takes into account using shared cell styles and fonts to avoid hitting the limits.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ExcelVaryFonts {
    
 //method for getting current font from cell
 private static Font getFont(Cell cell) {
  Workbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
  CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
  return workbook.getFontAt(style.getFontIndex());
 }

 private enum FontProperty {
  BOLD, COLOR, FONTHEIGHT, FONTNAME, ITALIC, STRIKEOUT, TYPEOFFSET, UNDERLINE
 }

 //method for getting font having special settings additional to given source font
 private static Font getFont(Workbook workbook, Font fontSrc, Map<FontProperty, Object> fontproperties) {
  boolean isBold = fontSrc.getBold();
  short color = fontSrc.getColor();
  short fontHeight = fontSrc.getFontHeight();
  String fontName = fontSrc.getFontName();
  boolean isItalic = fontSrc.getItalic();
  boolean isStrikeout = fontSrc.getStrikeout();
  short typeOffset = fontSrc.getTypeOffset();
  byte underline = fontSrc.getUnderline();

  for (FontProperty property : fontproperties.keySet()) {
   switch (property) {
    case BOLD:
     isBold = (boolean)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case COLOR:
     color = (short)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case FONTHEIGHT:
     fontHeight = (short)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case FONTNAME:
     fontName = (String)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case ITALIC:
     isItalic = (boolean)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case STRIKEOUT:
     isStrikeout = (boolean)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case TYPEOFFSET:
     typeOffset = (short)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
    case UNDERLINE:
     underline = (byte)fontproperties.get(property);
    break;
   }
  }

  Font font = workbook.findFont(isBold, color, fontHeight, fontName, isItalic, isStrikeout, typeOffset, underline);
  if (font == null) {
   font = workbook.createFont();
   font.setBold(isBold);
   font.setColor(color);
   font.setFontHeight(fontHeight);
   font.setFontName(fontName);
   font.setItalic(isItalic);
   font.setStrikeout(isStrikeout);
   font.setTypeOffset(typeOffset);
   font.setUnderline(underline);
  }

  return font;
 }
                
 private static void writeCell(Student stu, Cell cell) {
  Map<String, Object> styleproperties = null;
  Map<FontProperty, Object> fontproperties = null;
  
  Workbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
  
  cell.setCellValue(stu.getName());
  
  //get or create the needed font 20pt
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTHEIGHT, (short)(20*20));
  Font font20 = getFont(workbook, getFont(cell), fontproperties);
  //get or create the needed font 17pt
  fontproperties = new HashMap<FontProperty, Object>();
  fontproperties.put(FontProperty.FONTHEIGHT, (short)(17*20));
  Font font17 = getFont(workbook, getFont(cell), fontproperties);
  
  //create style propertes for cell
  styleproperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  if (stu.isLongName()) {
   styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FONT, font17.getIndex());
  } else {
   styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FONT, font20.getIndex());
  }
  
  if (stu.isBoarding()) {
   styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, IndexedColors.PALE_BLUE.getIndex());
   styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  } else {
   styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
   styleproperties.put(CellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  }
  
  //set style properties to cell
  CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, styleproperties);  
 }
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xlsx"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xlsx";
  //String inFilePath = "./ExcelExampleIn.xls"; String outFilePath = "./ExcelExampleOut.xls";
  
  Student[][] students = new Student[][] {
   new Student[]{new Student("Jane", true, false), new Student("John has a long name", false, true), new Student("Foo", true, false)},   
   new Student[]{new Student("Bar has a very long name", true, true), new Student("Stud", false, false)},   
   new Student[]{new Student("Next student having a long name", true, true), new Student("Bar", false, false), new Student("Test", true, false)},   
  };

  try (Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath ) ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

   for (int r = 0; r < students.length; r++) {
    Row row = CellUtil.getRow(r, sheet);
    for (int c = 0; c < students[r].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = CellUtil.getCell(row, c);
     writeCell(students[r][c], cell);
    }
   }
   
   workbook.write(out);
  }
 }
}
```

Used `Student` class for completeness:

```
public class Student {
 private String name;
 private boolean boarding;
 private boolean longName;
 public Student(String name, boolean boarding, boolean longName) {
  this.name = name;
  this.boarding = boarding; 
  this.longName = longName; 
 }
 public String getName() {
  return this.name;   
 }
 public boolean isBoarding() {
  return this.boarding;   
 }
 public boolean isLongName() {
  return this.longName;   
 }
}
```

Comment: Actually in my input file, the cells have boarders, that's why I create a new style for every cell, but I haven't considered about shared font, I will try it.

Comment: And there are only about 50 cells left to be modified, so I think it will be easier to create a new style for every single cell though it's not the standard way.

Comment: @Rocket: My solution is keeping all present cell style properties inclusive borders. It only sets/adds the given properties in `styleproperties` to the present cell styles.

Comment: Good answer, you've solved my problem, thanks.